# Hide button afterRender based on callback result

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, rerender, callback

I'm trying to hide buttons depending on some information that the callback function on "INIT" should give as result.

I'm trying to do it into a custom render "afterRender" as described in salesforce documentation. 
But when the afterRender function execute the callback has not arrived yet from the server and Attribute value aren't changed yet!

Do you know the best way to add class to "lightning:button" (for example) based on callback results?

Comment: Simply find the element with add and add the class(to hide / show) based on the logic.

Comment: Well, I did it before using afterRender, but component wasn't working....Now I did it again...and It's working....sometimes it takes long time for lightning experience to reload the right version of component! Btw, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `afterRender` to hide `lightning:button`. You can have an attribute and set its value based on the data returned from the callback.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="buttonVisiblity" type="Map" default="{'btn1':'slds-show','btn2':'slds-show','btn3':'slds-show'}" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Button1" class="{!v.buttonVisibility.btn1}" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Button2" class="{!v.buttonVisibility.btn2}" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Button3" class="{!v.buttonVisibility.btn3}" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />

</aura:component>
```

callback:

```
action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
    var data = result.getReturnValue();
    var btnVisibility = component.get("v.buttonVisiblity");
    if(data != 'btn1') {
        btnVisibility.btn1 = 'slds-hide';
    }  

    if(data != 'btn2'){
        btnVisibility.btn2 = 'slds-hide';
    }

    if(data != 'btn3'){
        btnVisibility.btn3 = 'slds-hide';
    }
    component.set("v.buttonVisiblity",btnVisibility);
});
```